# rpm signature verification fails on CentOS, works on Fedora

Tags: centos, fedora, rpm, yum, gnupg

Why does the following work on Fedora (28), but not on CentOS (7.5)?

```
wget https://download.fman.io/1.3.5/fman.rpm
sudo rpm -v --import https://download.fman.io/rpm/public.gpg
rpm -K fman.rpm
```

On Fedora, I get

```
fman.rpm: digests signatures OK
```

whereas on CentOS:

```
fman.rpm: RSA sha1 ((MD5) PGP) md5 NOT OK (MISSING KEYS: (MD5) PGP#9cfaf7eb)
```

Perhaps the problem is the following: When I do `gpg --import public.gpg` followed by `gpg --list-keys`, I get:

```
pub   4096R/44B73575 2016-11-21
uid                  Michael Herrmann <my email>
sub   4096R/C98DD00E 2016-11-21
sub   4096R/9CFAF7EB 2016-11-21
```

Note how `44B7...` is the parent key, and `9CFA...` is the sub-key mentioned in the CentOS message above.

Now, when I do `rpm -q gpg-pubkey --qf '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}\t%{SUMMARY}\n'`, I get:

```
gpg-pubkey-44b73575-58333336    gpg(Michael Herrmann <my email>)
```

So `rpm` has the parent key `44b7...`. It seems it's unable to go from that to the sub-key.

Possibly related:

- [Bad signatures or NOKEY errors on RPMs I just signed](https://serverfault.com/questions/624888/bad-signatures-or-nokey-errors-on-rpms-i-just-signed)

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of RPM did not support sub key signatures.